# Domain of a function with square root, log and... more (man vs machine)

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

I have this function:

$y=\sqrt{\ln|\sin^2x-3\cos^2x|}$

I'm pretty sure its domain is:

$-\pi/4 + k \pi \leq x \leq \pi/4 + k \pi \; \; \cup\; \; x=\pi/2 + k \pi$

I got it by solving $\ln|\sin^2x-3\cos^2x|\geq 0 \Rightarrow |\sin^2x-3\cos^2x| \geq 1$.

To be sure, I "tested" it but every graph calculator draws the function only in the first interval but not in the $\pi/2$ points (where the function should be $0$). Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your domain is correct; plotting
$|\sin^2(x)-3\cos^2(x)|$ reveals that the domain on which it is greater than or equal to zero is indeed the domain you gave. Maybe the reason why graph calculators don't find the $\pi/2$ point is because it's harder for them to find isolated points where the function is defined.

I tried plotting $\sqrt{-x^2}$ on desmos and it found the point where it is defined, but it somehow didn't work for $\sqrt{-\cos^2(x)}$.

Conclusion: don't trust machines.

Comment: Thank you very much!! The test you did is kinda funny :D